# Spawning GDM/Display manager within already existing X11 session

Tags: linux, xorg, x11

I know that this is possible, I've seen it done, but I've forgotten the command.

Basically, what I want to do (for various reasons) is to spawn a GDM/Gnome/etc session (a new one) from within my current session.  I don't want to use another tty. I want it to be windowed, and appear under my current session, so I can easily Alt+Tab, start/stop the session easily.

Ideally I'll be able to do something to the effect of: `<command> /path/to/gdm`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly `xnest` or `xephyr` - these both let you start up an X session in a window.

Comment: Yep, these were what I was after, unfortunately seems not compatible with my end goal, but the question is answered.

Comment: What is your end goal? Maybe we can refine these answers. Maybe ask another question?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above two mentioned commands, you can also use:

> gdmflexiserver